# Breaks loop even if condition is met

Tags: c#, loops

I need to make a simple progam that lets the user enter if they want to try to get 7, 14 or 21 in 3 rolls with a dice.

My class dice looks like this:

```
class Dobbelsteen
{
    private int zichtbaar; // value of dice
    Random random = new Random();

    public int getNummer   //Show value of dice
    {
        get { return zichtbaar; }
    }


    public Dobbelsteen()
    {
        zichtbaar = 0;

    }

    public void Gooien()
    {
        zichtbaar = random.Next(1, 7);          
    }
}
```

This should be fine.

But now in my main something goes wrong; it asks it 3 times and if they are lucky it breaks (Good) but now the part that fails.
If it doesnt work they have to type anything to try again but if 0 is typed it stops.
In my case it just always breaks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        int gekozengetal; //Chosen number 7,14 or 21


            Console.WriteLine("Je mag 3 keer met de dobbelsteen gooien. Wil je proberen 7, 14 of 21 te werpen?"); // Asks to give 7 14 or 21 to play;
            gekozengetal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // saves that in this int;

            while (gekozengetal== 7 || gekozengetal == 14 || gekozengetal == 21)
            {
                int opgeteld = 0;   // this is the values combined of the rolls.

                Dobbelsteen test = new Dobbelsteen();
                Console.WriteLine("Druk om je eerste dobbelsteen te gooien");
                Console.ReadKey();
                test.Gooien();
                opgeteld += test.getNummer;
                Console.WriteLine("Je eerste Dobbel was" + opgeteld);
                Console.WriteLine("Druk om je TWEEDE dobbelsteen te gooien");
                Console.ReadKey();
                test.Gooien();
                opgeteld += test.getNummer;
                Console.WriteLine("Je tweede Dobbel was" + test.getNummer +" samen is dit al" + opgeteld);
                Console.WriteLine("Druk om je DERDE dobbelsteen te gooien");
                Console.ReadKey();
                test.Gooien();
                opgeteld += test.getNummer;
                Console.WriteLine("Je derde Dobbel was" + test.getNummer + " samen is dit al" + opgeteld);


                if (opgeteld == gekozengetal)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HOERA, GEWONNEN.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;

                }


                else
                {
    Console.WriteLine("Loser je moest" +gekozengetal +" hebben en je bent" +opgeteld + "uitgekomen"); // Too bad; you didnt get lucky
    Console.WriteLine("WE GAAN OPNIEUW PROBEREN: DRUK 0 om te stoppen"); // Lets try again; press 0 to abort.
    int opnieuw = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey()); // Opnieuw = again
    if (opnieuw == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to have a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/). It's harder to follow your code if it's in a foreign language.

Comment: I don't speak this language, so I'll try my best, but try and get the value for opnieuw (I hope I spelled that correctly) before you do the check on the final 6 lines and check that it's what you're expecting?

Comment: what do you expect? you're doing `convert.toint32` on your input. if someone enters `a`, how should that be converted to an int?

Comment: You also don't need that closing } else { since it would just re-iterate if you hadn't broke the iteration in the previous if {

Comment: Actually : convert.toint32 with a value of 'a' passed would:

Converted the Char value 'a' to the Int32 value 97. 

as it returns:

A 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded code point of the value parameter.

Comment: I added some comments for translation, sorry guys.

Comment: when you say "it breaks" - what happens? Is an error thrown? Or does something not happen?

Comment: Okay here:

    int opnieuw = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
    Console.WriteLine(opnieuw);
    if (opnieuw == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

Check the value of the integer.

Comment: Maybe I should add a try catch for if they enter something that is not 7 14 or 21 it just restarts.

Comment: You know that the user will not enter the loop if `gekozengetal` is something other than 7, 14 or 21? (and that you can't get 21 in 3 throws of a 6-sided dice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the MSDN documentation, Console.ReadKey() returns an object of type ConsoleKeyInfo. Convert.ToInt32 should not be able to convert an object of that type to int. So as soon as you get to the part where you read the next key from the console and try to convert it to int, Convert.ToInt32 should throw an exception (InvalidCastException).

ConsoleKeyInfo has a property "KeyChar" which holds the key that was pressed as a char. You can check if that is equal to '0' and end your program:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo kinfo = Console.ReadKey();
char keyPressed = kinfo.KeyChar;
if (keyPressed.Equals('0')
{
    break;
}
else
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the whole thing!
Do you by any chance know the try catch to reset it when they didnt enter something else than 7 14 21?

Tried FormatException e
Console.WriteLine(e.Message) but doesnt seem to work properly.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. I assume you mean that your program ends after the user enters a target number other than 7, 14 or 21. That is because you included that condition into your while-statement. So the program will stop going through the while-loop as soon as a user enters something other than 7, 14 or 21. That's generally a bad design for program flow. It would be better to use a simple exit condition for your while-loop and verify the user input within the loop. If the user supplies an invalid number, ask him again until he either aborts (exit the loop) or supplies a valid input.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's really hard to interpret this code. But I guess that the following condition could be the culprit:

```
int opnieuw = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey()); // Opnieuw = again
if (opnieuw == 0)
{
    break;
}
else
{
    continue;
}
```

You see 'Console.ReadKey() returns an object of class ConsoleKeyInfo, something which you cannot directly convert to int. I would suggest you to change the code to the following:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo opnieuw = Console.ReadKey(); // Opnieuw = again
if (opnieuw == ConsoleKey.D0 || opnieuw == ConsoleKey.NumPad0)
{
    break;
}
else
{
    continue;
}
```